# Laravel Auth::attempt from example in Laravel PHP Starter book only returns false

Tags: authentication, laravel

I believe I followed the steps in the book exactly, but cannot get the user to be logged in even if I supply the credentials in the array manually.

Could someone take a look below and see where I went wrong?

There is a table called users which was created using Migrations earlier and a row with the email = 'test@test.com' and password = 'test'.

Thanks so much.

### routes.php

```
Route::any('login', 'auth@login');
```

### controllers/auth.php

```
class Auth_Controller extends Base_Controller 
{
    public function get_login()
    {
        return View::make('auth.login');
    }

    public function post_login()
    {
        $credentials = array(
            'username' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            return "User has been logged in.";
        }
        else
        {
            //return Redirect::back()->with_input();
            return "User has not been logged in.";
        }        
    }
}
```

### auth/login.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open() }}

    Email: {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }} <br />

    Password: {{ Form::password('password') }} <br />

    {{ Form::submit('Login') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

### config/auth.php

```
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'username' => 'email',
'password' => 'password',
'model' => 'User',
'table' => 'users',
```

### models/user.php

```
class User extends Eloquent
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndrewB from the Laravel forum answered this:

> Ok, the built in authentication expects the password to be hashed -
>   you can create a hash using Hash::make('mypassword') and put the
>   result into your database, then you should be able to login.
>
> @AndrewB, that did it. The example in the book did not use Hash, but
>   when I added your suggestion to the post_update function to edit the
>   user, that worked.
>
> THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using restful controllers "get_login() & post_login()" but you've not declared it as restful. You'll need to add the property to your "user" controller

```
class Auth_Controller extends Base_Controller 
{
    public $restful = true;
    ...
```

You can also add it to the base controller
If you are working from the same tutorial as i am "Laravel Starter by Shawn McCool" then he mentions this on page no 19

```
class Base_Controller extends Controller
{
    public $restful = true;
    ....
```

My (copy & paste) code works b.t.w. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure field username actually stores email address.

Comment: The username in the auth config is set to 'email' and the email column in the users table has only email addresses in it.