# Laravel Authentification fails

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller

I got a problem, my Authentifications keeps getting to the else statement, while I put in the correct email and password into the login form. With the else statement I mean the last line of my SessionController

```
    else 

    {
       return Redirect::to('login')
    }
```

Here are my routes.php

```
// ~ Root
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'root', 'uses' => 'PageController@showIndex'));

// ~ Session ~ Login ~ Logout
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'newSession', 'uses' => 'SessionController@newSession'));
Route::post('login', array('as' => 'setSession', 'uses' => 'SessionController@setSession'));
Route::get('logout', array('as' => 'destroySession', 'uses' => 'SessionController@destroySession'));
```

And here is my SessionController

```
<?php

class SessionController extends BaseController {

    public function newSession() {

        $this->layout->content = View::make('login');

    }

    public function setSession() {

        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } else {

            // create our user data for the authentication
            $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password')
            );

            // attempt to do the login
            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

                return Redirect::to('asd');

            } else {
                return Redirect::to('login')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
                // validation not successful, send back to form
                // return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
            }
        }
    }

    public function destroySession() {

        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'You are logged out'); 

    }
}
```

And this is my form

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'SessionController@setSession', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal navbar-form navbar-right')) }}
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>
            {{ $errors->first('email') }}
            {{ $errors->first('password') }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address', array('class' => 'navLogTxt')) }}          
            {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}      
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Passwort', array('class' => 'navLogTxt')) }}            
            {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            {{ Form::submit('Anmelden!', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
        </p>                        
    </div>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And at last this is my Seeder

```
<?php

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {

        DB::table('users')->delete();
        User::create(array(
            'email'    => 'test@mail.de',
            'password' => Hash::make('awesome')
        ));
        User::create(array(
            'email'    => 'test@mail2.de',
            'password' => 'test'
        ));

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the password encrypted in your database or is it stored as plain text?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15673247/351330) to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: the password is stored as a plain text

Comment: its actually both I mad one as a plain text and another one encrypted, both won't work

Comment: Did you use `Hash::make('yourpassword');` to generate the hashed password before saving it into the database?

Comment: looks like this 
DB::table('users')->delete();
     User::create(array(
         'email'    => 'test@mail.de',
         'password' => Hash::make('awesome')
     ));

Comment: What's the length of the `password` column in your `users` table? It should be at least 60 charachters, so `VARCHAR(60)`.

Comment: Hi again  it's a varchar 50, shall I change it?

Comment: Yes, I've posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the [Laravel Authentication Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication):

> Remember: when building the database schema for this model, **make the password column at least 60 characters**. Also, before getting started, make sure that your users (or equivalent) table contains a nullable, string remember_token column of 100 characters.

For future reference, Laravel ships with a migration for the `users` table which you can find in `database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`. You can use that to generate the `users` table by running `php artisan migrate`.

You can of course add additional columns aside from the default ones defined there, just read the [Schema Builder Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema) for more information.

Comment: After you resized the column to be 60 charachters, did you recreate the user? Because the password value would still be 50 chars if you wouldn't re-hash it.